# JPA Cacheable specific example on how to use it

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am kind of new to JPA and have read a bit about second level caching in JPA. And I think it should apply correctly to my scenario.
I have a table (say A) whose content will never change unless a new release is applied.
I need to query some data from the database : for that I have a JPQL working correctly and that uses a join between table A and an additional table (say B).

Since the contents of table A never change through the life of application, I could essentially mark this table A as Cacheable and reuse the content from Cache - rather than going to the database for that.

I have read about @NamedQuery that enables a one time JPQL to SQL translation for the life of the application. And it is not what I am looking for.

I want to know how should I go about using the Cacheable property for my purpose.

This is what I have done so far :

1. Marked tableA as cacheable -

   @Entity
   @Cacheable
   @Table(name = "TableA")
   public class Table{

   ```
   @Id
   @NotNull
   @Column(updatable = false)
   private String uuid;

   @NotNull
   @Size(min = 1)
   private String description;
   ```

   .
   .
   .
   }

2. There is a DAO that does a find using the JPQL - 
    

    `public Collection findAll(String description) {
    final Cache cache = entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache();
    if (cache.contains(TableA.class, "abc")) {
        System.out.println("cached");
    } else {
        System.out.println("not cached");
    }
    final Query query = entityManager
            .createQuery("Select distinct A from TableA A, IN(A.TableB) B where A.description = :description"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    query.setParameter("description", description); //$NON-NLS-1$`

```
return query.getResultList();
}

  </code>
```

Can I take advantage of using Cacheable property in my scenario. If so, then could you suggest how?
Also, "not cached" gets printed always no matter what the value of string I use (from table) instead of "abc".

Appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Did you enabled Second Level cache ?

Comment: Hi Mani, thanks for replying - yes I have the "<shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>" in persistence.xml